# R fitting quasipoisson glm with joint modeling of dispersion

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I'd like to fit a quasipoisson model with joint modeling of dispertion parameter.

I have 3 quelitatives covariates, so the parameters to estimate are indexed on i,j,k. The model is :

[image]

I want to differentiate the $\phi$ on the covariates, and putting a \phi_{i,j,k} instead.

I know it's possible (chapter 10 of McCullagh and Nelder (1989) : http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/2201s11/readings/glmbook.pdf ), at least mathematicaly, but i did not find the way to fit this kind of model in R.

I'm aware of the `dhglm` package, that allow to do this, but only for the Poisson family, and not for the quasipoisson (i.e in a GLM framework and not a quasi-glm framework). The thing is that i have negatives values in my data, wich the poisson family can't take, but the quasi-poisson framework dont break if at least the marginal sums of data for each parameter is'nt negative. ( see this post : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-January/028743.html and the Dadiv Firth answer).

does someone as seen some modelisation and implementations of such models ? If so, references ?

Comment: This might be a better question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For here, the question is not well constructed. Share your code attempt thus far. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Folowing what you adviced me, i re-posted with more clear detals here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331277/non-linear-high-dim-equations-solving-quasi-mle